# F#: How to calculate Hamming distance?

Tags: algorithm, f#

I am new to F#. This is my first functional programming language.

I would like to write an algorithm to calculate the Hamming distance between two strings of equal length. How would one do so in F#? Any examples consisting of pseudocode would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Seq.map2` to compare corresponding values then sum the differences:

```
let hamming s1 s2 = Seq.map2((=)) s1 s2 |> Seq.sumBy(fun b -> if b then 0 else 1)
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe consider this http://davefancher.com/tag/hamming-distance/? Or is there any particular reason that it is not meeting your requirements? From the linked page:

```
let hammingDistance (source : string) (target : string) =
  if source.Length <> target.Length then failwith "Strings must be equal length"

  Array.zip (source.ToCharArray()) (target.ToCharArray())
  |> Array.fold (fun acc (x, y) -> acc + (if x = y then 0 else 1)) 0

hammingDistance "abcde" "abcde" |> printfn "%i" // 0
hammingDistance "abcde" "abcdz" |> printfn "%i" // 1
hammingDistance "abcde" "abcyz" |> printfn "%i" // 2
hammingDistance "abcde" "abxyz" |> printfn "%i" // 3
hammingDistance "abcde" "awxyz" |> printfn "%i" // 4
hammingDistance "abcde" "vwxyz" |> printfn "%i" // 5
```